# How to arrive at this solution using Gauss elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

We were given a system of equations:
$$\lambda x+y+z=p$$
$$\lambda y+z+x=q$$
$$\lambda z+x+y=r$$
We are required to find the relations between $p,q,r,\lambda$ for the case when no solution exists for the given system.

So I created the augmented matrix:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \lambda&1&1&p\\
  1&\lambda&1&q\\
  1&1&\lambda&r 
\end{array}
\right] $$

Converting it to row-echelon form we get:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  \lambda&1&1&p\\
  0&\frac{\lambda^2-1}{\lambda}&\frac{\lambda-1}{\lambda}&q-\frac{p}{\lambda}\\
  0&0&\frac{\lambda^3-1}{\lambda^2+\lambda}&r+\frac{r-p-q}{\lambda} 
\end{array}
\right] $$

Now for no solution the matrix needs to have a degenerate case ie. one whole row of zeroes and a non-zero value on the RHS. So for this the possible cases are:

1. $\lambda=1$ and $p+q\ne 2r$
2. $\lambda=1$ and $p\ne q$

But on observation I also found another case that's possible ie. $\lambda=-2$
and $p+q+r\ne0$. How do I arrive at this using Gauss elimination because I can't see it in the augmented matrix?

Any help/alternate solution would be appreciated.

Comment: I did GE, but carefully not using $\lambda$ entries as pivots and got an equation $(\lambda-1)(2+\lambda)x=$something, so I suspect you've made a miustake.

Comment: When $\lambda=-2$, the sum of the three LHS columns is zero in the original system. It isn't in your row echelon form. You made a mistake: How did you get to $\frac{\lambda^3-1}{\lambda^2+\lambda}$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician You are right. I also get the same form when not using $\lambda$ as pivot.

Comment: Switch the first and third row.  Then row-echelon is done in one step.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe In your method we need to divide by $\lambda -1$, is that allowed since we have no idea whether it'snon-zero or not?

Comment: No, your have to consider the case $\lambda -1=0$ seperately before dividing.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Ok I got it.